# Copying Assets to internal storage gives performance issues

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets

Copying Assets to internal storage slows down my application and takes a lot of time to load. Since, I want my application to run offline, I need those asset files to be copied.

But, do I have to copy every file each time I run my application ? Can I just copy the files that I have made changes to ? Might be a noob question. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't.  You only have to copy it in 2 circumstances:

1)This is the first time your app is running.
2)The app was just upgraded and you need to copy over the new asset.  There's several ways to check this.  An easy way is to write the version of assets you've copied over to shared preference, then check if it matches the version number of your app.  If they match, you don't need to rewrite the assets.

So the combined pseudocode is

```
if(sharedPreference.get(VersionNumber, -1) != App version number){
  copyFromAssets();
}
```

Comment: Thanks gabe. This is quite useful. I have one more doubt. If I uninstall the app and then install again, sharedPrefernce will copy assets again... Right ?

Comment: If you uninstall the app, there would be no preferences so it should copy again. If you want to be defensive, you can check for the existence of the chopped file in an or to that condition.

Comment: Okay got it. Thank You so much. When I make changes to files inside the application, I have to update the version number.... ?